# Exclamation mark doesn't work in UTM parameters

Tags: google-analytics, analytics, utm, facebook-ads

I have a quick question. Why exclamation mark doesn't work in UTM parameters.

I will give you an example - this url which is generated by external tool doesn't work and redirect to home page:

```
https://www.example_site.com/xx/xx/xxx?utm_source=facebook&utm_medium=cpc&utm_term=XX&utm_campaign=Test_Test_Test&utm_id=xx1!12345678
```

But when i manually delete ! mark from utm_id (last part) it starts working:

```
https://www.example_site.com/xx/xx/xxx?utm_source=facebook&utm_medium=cpc&utm_term=XX&utm_campaign=Test_Test_Test&utm_id=xx112345678
```

utm_id is generated automatically so I cannot change it other way then manually all the time.

How could I solve this problem and why this is happening?

Comment: Why do you expect it to work? Any exclamation points in URLs should probably be percent-encoded, like `%21`.

Comment: Actually - "%" mark behave in the same way as "!". I check another characters and so far "#" and "?" marks are working as I expect.